# Find matching folder in Crystal Reports

Tags: hyperlink, crystal-reports

I'm trying to return a folder path, given a variable that partially matches, using Crystal Reports syntax.

For example, given a variable `{tbl.ProjectNumber} = 0152`, return folder path `Z:/Work/Projects/0152 Acme Construction` from directory `Z:/Work/Projects`, where `Z:/Work/Projects` is set up as:

```
...
Z:/Work/Projects/0151 Lumber Corp
Z:/Work/Projects/0152 Acme Construction
Z:/Work/Projects/0153 Computer Barn
...
```

Ultimately to pass out the path as a 'hyperlink to file' path.

The code below gets me close, but there are many text inconsistencies between the database field names (.ProjectName) and the actual folder names. Such as .ProjectName could be 'Lumber Corporation', but actual folder to hyperlink to is /0151 Lumber Corp.  That's why I need to get at it by number.

```
stringvar text:="";
text:= "Z:/Work/Projects/"&{tblProjectsInfo.ProjectNumber}&" "&{tblProjectInfo.ProjectName}
```

** Update: Thanks for looking Siva. I need a text string of the path that matches the project number, such as "Z:/Work/Projects/0151 Lumber Corp".  This would all be in a formula within a Crystal Reports 'Format Field' --> Hyperlink, as a conditional hyperlink to file.

It works with my provided code, except that frequently produces broken links (due to Corp vs Corporation, misspelling, etc.).  Any and all thoughts are greatly appreciated.

** `ProjectNumber` will be 4 digit numeric.  `ProjectName` will be an indeterminate length string.

** Inconsistent naming in example is fixed.

** Extraneous info removed.

### Final Update

Thanks for looking.  No solution found, ended up just exporting all `ProjectName` and `ProjectNumber` fields to a .csv and doing a batch rename on the folders to remove inconsistencies.

Comment: what output you need from the formula? any example

Comment: At one `if` you used `project number` and at other `permitnumber`.. which one is correct? and also what values will be present in `project number` and `project name`